# Spring data mongodb - set query timeout

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

There is an option to kill slow queries in DBCursor using maxTime() method, do we have an equivalent method in Spring data mongodb query.

I have to kill specific slow queries in Spring data mongodb.

Please provide your suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open ticket for the support of `cursor.maxTime` (see [DATAMONGO-957](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-957)).

What you could do is using your own `CursorPreparer` to add the required data. You'll have to tweak a few classes.

```
class MyQuery extends Query {
    long timeout;
}

class MyCursorPreparer implements CursorPreparer {

    private final Query query;
    private final Class<?> type;

    public MyCursorPreparer(Query query, Class<?> type) {

        this.query = query;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public DBCursor prepare(DBCursor cursor) {

        // add timeout options
        if (query instanceof MyQuery) {
            long timeout = ((MyQuery) query).timeout;
            if (timeout > 0) {
                cursor = cursor.maxTime(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        }

        // ... do other preparation stuff

        return cursor;
    }
}

class MyTemplate extends MongoTemplate {

    public MyTemplate(Mongo mongo, String databaseName) {
        super(mongo, databaseName);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> List<T> find(final Query query, Class<T> entityClass, String collectionName) {

        if (query == null) {
            return findAll(entityClass, collectionName);
        }

        return doFind(collectionName, query.getQueryObject(), 
          query.getFieldsObject(), entityClass, 
          new MyCursorPreparer(query, entityClass));
    }

    @Override
    public void executeQuery(Query query, String collectionName, DocumentCallbackHandler dch) {
        executeQuery(query, collectionName, dch, new MyCursorPreparer(query, null));
    }

}
```